# Where are exception codes documented for microsoft applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I am running an application compiled with MSVC, I am experiencing an exception that is being caught and reported as Exception=0xc000008f. The application is written in C++;

Can someone help me find where these exception codes are documented?

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\excpt.h

Comment: ntstatus.h SDK header file.  It is used by the VBA/VB6 runtime to implement On Error, the kind of detail you'll only find back at Google.

Comment: Well, while you are debugging the program, you just have to **open the exception window and type the error code in the search box** and find the description in no time at all. I am very surprised that the debugger didn't show you that information when the exception occured. And if you don't understand the probelm, try Google search... Often the error lookup tool is even faster but for some reason it does not find that error code.

Answer (score 1):

The main place to look is the winerror.h file shipped in the SDK. (Usually found at c:\program files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include<version>\share\winerror.h). Sometimes the constants will be found in other files either also in shared or sometimes in um.

I tend to use a command line grep for performing such searches, though the Visual Studio "find in files" can also be made to search the include paths.

I will add that the exact error you ask about is called "ATUS_FLOAT_INEXACT_RESULT" and is defined in ntstatus.h rather than winerror.h

Comment: Let me just add to this.  Look into the Win32 function `FormatMessage`   You will find it quite useful for turning Win32 error codes into human-readable messages.  I have been using a utility function that does this for 25 years.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage

Comment: While it does not work for that specific error, in Visual Studio tools menu, there is an item for error lookup that do works for many common errors.